# POST405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am using AngularJS to send a POST request from my controller and I'm getting this error:

> POST not supported

The JS function is the following:

```
  addUserDetails: function(addUser) {
      alert("M into add user function in service");
      return restClientTemplate.execute({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'json/user-add',
          data: addUser
      });
  }
```

My Java Spring Controller is the following:

```
@Controller
public class AddUserController {

    @Resource
    private Settings settings;

    @Resource
    private RestOperations rest;

    private static final String ORGANIZATION_URL_KEY = "configuration.organization.service.endpointUrl";
    private static final String ORG_PRODUCT_LIST_URL_KEY = "configuration.org.product.list.service.endpointUrl";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/json/user-add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ServiceResponse addOrganization(@RequestBody SaveOrganizationForm request) {  
        System.out.println("M into controllerrrr");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode requestBody = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        populateRequestObject(request, objectMapper, requestBody);

        String url = MessageUtil.format(settings.getString(ORGANIZATION_URL_KEY) + "/s2");

        ServiceResponse response = rest
            .exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(requestBody), ServiceResponse.class).getBody();

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: What REST-library are you using on the back-end?

Comment: You are missing a closing brace(`}`).

Comment: spring rest services m using

Comment: brace is there i missed it while pasting it here

Comment: add consumes="application/json" to your request mapping